# Navigation with icon to open page and open popover top

Tags: navigation, icons, popover

This is my first participation here so apologies if I am not doing this right.

My question is about about using icons for navigation.

For example:

[image]

All items are clickable

1) The first item (My Works) open popover with list all works

2) The Job(Briefcase) icon will open a page

3) People(User) Icon will open a page

4) Notification icon will open a popover

5) "Logo" will open a popover

Do you think bad UX?
I have seen this being used in Gmail, StackExchange, Instagram and I am heading towards a similar solution.

What do you think about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would think it's ok.

Be aware though: Exactly these questions can result in hours of discussions without clear outcome.

So the best way to save time and be really sure is to test it: Just grab some 3–5 friends or colleagues, and let them test it, one at a time, without the others.

- Don't tell them what you want exactly to test
- Ask them what they see (without interacting) in your header and what they expect the buttons to do
- Tell them to think aloud when they interact, so that you can understand their expectations and reactions
- Let them navigate those buttons one by one
- If they don't voice their reaction by themselves you can ask: "Was that what you expected?"

If you want to know more about these light-weight tests, I can recommend Steven Krug's book "Rocket Surgery made easy".

It's true that everything influences the user's experience, but this is more a classical Usability Question.